# Getting Typeahead.js to work with Fat Free Framework

Tags: typeahead.js, fat-free-framework

I am trying to get twitter typeahead.js to work with my Fat Free Framework setup, but am failing so far.

My PHP code in the SearchController:

```
function itemsearch($f3){ // search


    $query = filter_var($f3->get('PARAMS.string'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $db=$f3->get('DB');


        $result = $db->exec("
        SELECT * FROM items 
        WHERE itemName LIKE '%$query%'

        ");

        echo json_encode($result);
}
```

My route:

```
$f3->route('GET /search/item/@string','SearchController->itemsearch');
```

if I call this route directly through the browser I get a nice json result with my query.

My HTML / jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var items = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {

        url: '{{@BASE}}/search/item/$QUERY',
        filter: function (items) {

            return $.map(items.results, function (item) {
                return {
                    value: item.itemName
                };
            });
        }
    }
});



items.initialize();


$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: items.ttAdapter()
});
});
```

If I use this code with the url replaced by a test url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%QUERY&api_key=470fd2ec8853e25d2f8d86f685d2270e' I get nice typeahead results, but with my own URL (in the code above) nothing happens.

How can I get this to work with Fat Free Framework?

Comment: is `{{@BASE}}` properly replaced in your JS? Have you checkd the dev console?

Comment: Also you seem to have forgotten braces around `$QUERY`: `{{@BASE}}/search/item/{{$QUERY}}`

Comment: I made an error there too: it should be %QUERY, without braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I made a simple error, the documentation was not clear about this:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
displayKey:'value',
source: items.ttAdapter()
});
```

Should have been

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
displayKey:'itemName',
source: items.ttAdapter()
});
```

so the displayKey value should be the 'item' you are searching for in the json result. In my case the json returned

```
itemName:whatever
```

so my displayKey value should be **itemName** in order to display the value **whatever**